# How to click on a video using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, video

I'm new to coding using python and it's libraries, and also new to stackoverflow so I apologize if I'm not acquainted to some things.

Anyway to the question. I'm trying to write code that automates playing a video from the website that. Here's an example link:

http://www.shush.se/index.php?id=164&show=southpark

I've tried these methods:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("playerload").click()

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("./html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div[@id='load']/div[@class='player']/div[@id='playerload']/div[1]")
```

But nothing happens. The program exits without error but the video does not 
start playing. 
I tried clicking a the id "jw6playerid5040619_wrapper" but the number associated with that changes every time a page loads.

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use a link that does not point to pirated content.

Comment: Should I remove the link from my OP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you don't know the exact id, you know that it will start with "jw6playerid". The following works for me:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'jw6playerid')]")
elements[0].click()
```

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of the contains method. Now I'll move on to trying to detect when the player has finished the episode. Appreciate the help!